# Django Query Values from a List of names

Tags: django

Is it possible to do a query from a list (or string) of desired values in Django?

```
v = ['a', 'b', 'c']  // or could be a sting like v = '"a","b","c"

qs = Data.objects.all().values ( v )
```

I am getting errors like:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Thank you.

Comment: Its not clear what are you trying to do.... Please do add more info

Comment: I am trying to select which values are in the query based on a list of names.

Comment: select from what? whcih field?

Comment: I don't want all the data, just a few of the values.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use queryset `filter` method and the `in` operator.

Your query should look something like this,

```py
qs = Data.objects.filter(prop_in=['a', 'b', 'c'])
# where prop is the field of Data you use to filter
```